# C++ Link list modifications using insert and remove

Tags: c++, function, insert, linked-list

I need to take the first linked list, and use the insert and remove functions to turn it into the second list that is commented. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this, because I dont know how to use the remove function or insert function more than once.

EDIT: I updated the code and I inserted and removed certain parts, and the program encounters a problem at the print function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Cafe
    {
    string item;
    int count;
    Cafe *link;
    };

typedef Cafe* CafePtr; 

void head_insert(CafePtr& head, string i, int c);
CafePtr searchnum(CafePtr& head, int target);
CafePtr searchstr(CafePtr& head, string target); 
void insert (CafePtr after_me, string i, int c);//insert a node in the list
void print (CafePtr head);                      //print the list
void remove(CafePtr before, CafePtr discard);   //remove a node from the list

int main(){

    CafePtr head;
    CafePtr iter, h;

    head = new Cafe;
    head->link = NULL;

    head_insert(head, "QL", 3808);
    head_insert(head, "CHGHS", 1312);
    head_insert(head, "REI", 10466);
    head_insert(head, "CPT", 1678);
    head_insert(head, "NetApp", 6887);
    head_insert(head, "EJ", 36937);
    head_insert(head, "WFM", 41717);
    head_insert(head, "SAS", 6046);
    head_insert(head, "BCG", 1958);
    head_insert(head, "Google", 18500);

    print (head);

    CafePtr before = searchstr(head, "Google"); 
    CafePtr discard = searchstr(head, "BCG");
    remove(before, discard);

    before = searchstr(head, "Google");
    discard = searchstr(head, "SAS"); 
    remove(before, discard);

    CafePtr after_me = searchstr(head, "Google");
    insert(after_me, "SAS", 6373);

    after_me = searchstr(head, "SAS");
    insert(after_me, "CHGHS", 1378);

    before = searchstr(head, "CHGHS");
    discard = searchstr(head, "WFM"); 
    remove(before, discard);

    after_me = searchstr(head, "CHGHS");
    insert(after_me, "BCG", 2314);

    before = searchstr(head, "BCG");
    discard = searchstr(head, "EJ"); 
    remove(before, discard);

    after_me = searchstr(head, "BCG");
    insert(after_me, "WFM", 43927);

    before = searchstr(head, "WFM");
    discard = searchstr(head, "NetApp"); 
    remove(before, discard);

    after_me = searchstr(head, "WFM");
    insert(after_me, "NetApp", 7426);

    before = searchstr(head, "NetApp");
    discard = searchstr(head, "CPT"); 
    remove(before, discard);

    after_me = searchstr(head, "NetApp");
    insert(after_me, "Hilcorp", 1012);

    before = searchstr(head, "Hilcorp");
    discard = searchstr(head, "REI"); 
    remove(before, discard);

    after_me = searchstr(head, "Hilcorp");
    insert(after_me, "EJ", 35114);

    //before = searchstr(head, "EJ");
    //discard = searchstr(head, "CHGHS"); <- If this bunch gets uncommented, the program breaks.
    //remove(before, discard);

/*  after_me = searchstr(head, "EJ");
    insert(after_me, "Ultimate", 1440);

    after_me = searchstr(head, "CHGHS"); //These things just need to be added after, these are the two final additions to the list
    insert(after_me, "CPT", 1896);
    */


    cout << endl;
    print(head); //If i remove this from the program, and uncomment the problem lines above, the program runs fine.
    return 0;

}

void head_insert(CafePtr& head, string i, int c)
{
    CafePtr temp_ptr;
    temp_ptr = new Cafe;

    temp_ptr -> item = i;
    temp_ptr -> count = c;

    temp_ptr -> link = head;
    head = temp_ptr;

}

CafePtr searchnum(CafePtr& head, int target)
{
    CafePtr here = head;

    if(here == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(here->count !=target && here->link != NULL)
            here = here->link;
        if(here->count == target)
            return here;
        else
            return NULL;
    }
}

CafePtr searchstr(CafePtr& head, string target)
{
    CafePtr here = head;

    if(here == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(here->item !=target && here->link != NULL)
            here = here->link;
        if(here->item == target)
            return here;
        else
            return NULL;
    }
}

void insert (CafePtr after_me, string i, int c)
{
    CafePtr temp_ptr;
    temp_ptr = new Cafe;
    temp_ptr->item = i;
    temp_ptr->count = c;

    temp_ptr->link = after_me->link;
    after_me->link = temp_ptr;          
}


void print (CafePtr head)
{

    for (CafePtr iter = head; iter !=NULL; iter=iter->link)
    {
        cout << (iter->item) << "\t" << (iter->count) << endl; //This line is where the debugger encounters a problem
    }
}

void remove(CafePtr before, CafePtr discard)
{
    before->link = discard->link;
    delete discard;                 
}
```

Comment: do you want implementations for remove and insert functions ?

Comment: I tried what you said Mohan, but I dont know what to change. Could you send me the code you worked on, so it is clear?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

You need to destroy one linked list and make a second one exact replica of the one you destroyed.

Lets go step by step.

```
1) Remove one element from head of linked list 1
2) Add the element thus removed to the end of list 2.
```

Or 
    1) Remove the element from tail of linked list 1
    2) Add the thus removed element to the head of linked list 2

Since it is a singular linked list, lets do approach 1/ - remove head of 1 and add to tail of 2

Before this, you need to add a null guard to your existing remove function.

```
 
// The second argument is not needed. before's link should be discard.
void remove(CafePtr before) // , CafePtr discard)
{
    CafePtr discard = before->link;
    // The guard. If before is the tail.
    if (discard != NULL)
        before->link = discard->link;
    // deletion on NULL has no effect so the above guard is unnecessary here.
    delete discard;
}
```

Now, we need to add a remove_head function.

```
// This will just remove the current head from linked list but won't delete the object.
CafePtr remove_head(CafePtr& head)
{
    if (head == NULL) return NULL;
    CafePtr to_discard = head;
    head = to_discard->link;
    to_discard->link = nullptr;
    return to_discard;
}
```

Now do your magic here.

I'll let you the remaining as homework. Let me know if it helps.

I have no clue what you are trying to do. But your current linked list method designs are wrong wrong.

In a standard singly linked list, the following should be the methods,

```
// Insert should accept preallocated toInsert element and a after pointer after which we want to insert
void insert(CafePtr toInsert, CafePtr after);
// Remove should accept the element to remove. If elemToRemove not found, it should return gracefully.
void remove(CafePtr elemToRemove);
```

The above kinda methods give more grace and more control.

But in the current code do this

```
before = searchstr(head, "SAS");
discard = searchstr(head, "CHGHS"); //<- If this bunch gets uncommented, the program breaks.
```

you will be ok.

First design your linked list and write what you want to do and [dry run](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_run_%28testing%29) your algorithm for debugging.

Comment: I am just confused on what to do. I think I see what you're saying. The goal of everything is to edit the linked list that I have, and turn it into the second linked list using insert and remove. I dont think I should have 2 separate linked lists.

Comment: So i changed the code, and I am adding the insert and delete parts. When i get to line 92, the program breaks. I run the debugger and the print function is where it breaks. I dont know what the problem is. I updated the question above, and there is a comment in the code where the problems occur.

Comment: while(here->item !=target && here->link != NULL)
            here = here->link;

If here reaches NULL, it will break.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure how to fix the problem. Could you tell me what I need to put in the program?

Comment: If you have visual studio, try doing F11, F10, you will know what would be happening

Comment: I did go through the debugger, thats how I found out that the print function had the problem. I just dont know how to fix it. Please

Comment: before = searchstr(head, "EJ");
    discard = searchstr(head, "CHGHS"); //<- If this bunch gets uncommented, the program breaks.
    remove(before, discard);

At this point, EJ's link is not "CHGHS"

Comment: How would I go about fixing the error then, can you show me the code that you made edits to? So i can see the problems, with your corrections?

Comment: @user2917900 I ve modified the answer to reflect your latest question. Dude, stackoverflow is not a community for your daily assignments. Every question in stackoverflow should add a community value and should reflect the research you did. Don't expect everything to be spoonfed here. Please go through some singly linked list implementation, you will get the glitch